# Nested Nuget Package

Tags: tfs, version-control, nuget

My problem is a bit complicated i hope i can explain well.

There are 2 interop dlls which are a product's dlls and one is for V10 and another is V16. Let calls it "MyComDll"

I have a project named MyWrapper that uses MyComDll. In TFS, I want to create nugetpage for V10 and V16. This is OK, i can do this but the problem I want to create two nuget packages. One nuget package uses MyComDll V10 and another uses MyComDll16.

After that, I have another project called MyLibrary that uses MyWrapper. In TFS i should also will be able to choose if it will be V10 or V16. According to this information MyWrapper nuget package must be V10 or V16.

And then, the same logic I have an application called MyApp that uses MyLibrary. According build configuration (V10 and V16), It must uses MyLibrary V10 or V16.

I draw this scenario

[image]

So how  i can make this?

Comment: You want to package these in TFS ? Could you please explain what you want to do?

Comment: Using TFS build and setting build configuration such as V10 or V16, I want to have a result which considering the build configuration (V10/V16). For example If i choose V16 then myApp project has to use MyLibrary that uses V16 and also MyLibrary has to use MyWrapper V16 and MyWrapper has to uses V16 and these are packages not added as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Make each thing into a NuGet package. You can specify dependencies on other NuGet packages in the `nuspec` file.

Comment: Then you cannot specify which you will use it by compiling time. For example in TFS, I chose V16 configuration and as a result it should create Nuget Package V16.

Answer (score 0):

TFS build does not have a feature like this 'I chose V16 configuration and as a result it should create Nuget Package V16'.

In TFS build, Which packages to restore are defined in the package.config file of your project. If you want to build different version of your project, you could use steps like [replace token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to change the assemblies defined in the package.config file before build. Or you could create 2 build definitions for each version.